# Upstart won't start my job

Tags: linux, daemon, upstart, python-daemon

I'm having hard time figuring out what's wrong with my script. I'm a newcomer to linux world so I may be missing something very trivial. I have a python script that I want to run a daemon when pc starts. I also want to respawn it in case of crash. After looking several hours in google, I gave up :)

Here's what I tried so far:

```
description "some daemon service."

#start on startup
#stop on shutdown
#respawn


pre-start exec python3 /home/dato0011/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py start

post-stop exec python3 /home/dato0011/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py stop
```

when executing initctl start "svc_name" I get **initctl: Job failed to start** error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your command is expected to go into the script section, not in the pre-start/post-start section. Otherwise the service won't start at all and wouldn't know which PID to track for respawn etc.

```
script
   exec python3 /home/dato011/PPycharmProjects/untitled/main.py start
end script
```

At stop upstart will kill your process with kill. I'm not entirely sure of how to kill it the way you specified by running the same command with a different parameter - in my case my (nodejs) application handles an event on exit and does any cleanup there.

Also, you don't need to use initctl to start and stop, just use the start and stop commands (i.e. start svc_name)